# javascript object get array of values from array of keys

Tags: javascript, key

I have an array of keys: `var keys = ["key1","key2","key3"]` and an array of Objects:

```
var objArr= [
    {"key0":1,"key1":2,"key2":3,"key3":4},
    {"key0":5,"key1":6,"key2":7,"key3":8}
]
```

I want to be able to get the values from the array of objects based off the array of keys. For example, the output of this would be `valueArr = [[2,3,4],[6,7,8]]`

I've tried the following:

```
var result = objArr.map(function(a) {
    for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
        return a[keys[i]];
    };
})
```

but this returns [2,6] because its just returning the first value it gets to. I'm not sure how to fix it so any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push `value` in array and return `array` from `Array#map`

```js
var keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"];
var objArr = [{
  "key0": 1,
  "key1": 2,
  "key2": 3,
  "key3": 4
}, {
  "key0": 5,
  "key1": 6,
  "key2": 7,
  "key3": 8
}];

var result = objArr.map(function(a) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    arr.push(a[keys[i]]);
  };
  return arr;
});
console.log(result);
```

Or using `Array#map` inside `Array#map`

```js
var keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"];
var objArr = [{
  "key0": 1,
  "key1": 2,
  "key2": 3,
  "key3": 4
}, {
  "key0": 5,
  "key1": 6,
  "key2": 7,
  "key3": 8
}];

var result = objArr.map(function(a) {
  return keys.map(function(key) {
    return a[key];
  });
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: same thing , you beat me

Comment: @ScottSelby You did ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

don't `return` too early , the loop only went through the first item :

```
var result = objArr.map(function(a) {
    var resp = [];
    for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
        resp.push(a[keys[i]]);            
    };
    return resp;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As an ***alternative***, you can use `Object.values()` function, as suggested [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). Example:

```
var objArr= [
    {"key0":1,"key1":2,"key2":3,"key3":4},
    {"key0":5,"key1":6,"key2":7,"key3":8}
];

for(var i in objArr){
    objArr[i] = Object.values(objArr[i]);
}
```

This is not supported by Internet Explorer, Opera or Safari at the moment though

Answer (score 1):

You coud use nested [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"],
    objArr = [{ "key0": 1, "key1": 2, "key2": 3, "key3": 4 }, { "key0": 5, "key1": 6, "key2": 7, "key3": 8 }],
    result = objArr.map(function (a) {
        return keys.map(function (k) {
            return a[k];
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"],
    objArr = [{ "key0": 1, "key1": 2, "key2": 3, "key3": 4 }, { "key0": 5, "key1": 6, "key2": 7, "key3": 8 }],
    result = objArr.map(a => keys.map(k => a[k]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Really like the ES6 variant ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the values onto an array, `return` will immediately break out of execution and *return* the value.

Try this:

```
var result = objArr.map(function(a) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
        res.push(a[keys[i]]);
    };
    return res;
})
```